# how to convert json to tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble, jsonlite

I have the following json data

```
{"data": {"cat1": ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"], "cat2": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]},"info": ""}
```

I want to convert the data to the following. How can I do that using function "fromJSON"

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data | cat1 | value1 |
| data | cat1 | value2 |
| data | cat1 | value3 |
| data | cat1 | value4 |
| data | cat1 | value5 |
| data | cat2 | aaa |
| data | cat2 | bbb |
| data | cat2 | ccc |
| info |  |  |

Comment: What did you try so far? What went wrong?

Comment: I just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a `tidyverse`-based solution to your problem using the `jsonlite` package. It is surprisingly easy to break down the list structure that the `fromJSON` creates when reading in the .JSON file. The rest is an application of `tidyverse` functionality. Note that the `Test.json` file contains the data exactly as you provided it.

**Code**

```
cols = c("var1", "var2", "var3")
A <- fromJSON("Test.json")
B <- A %>% 
      unique %>% 
        unlist %>% 
           as.data.frame %>% 
           tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
              mutate(rowname = substr(rowname, 1, nchar(rowname) - 1), 
               var1 = c(rep(names(A)[1], length(rowname) - 1), names(A)[2])) %>% 
                 rename(!!cols[1] := var1, !!cols[2] := rowname, !!cols[3] := .) %>% 
                    select(var1, var2, var3)
```

**Output**

```
  var1 var2   var3
1 data cat1 value1
2 data cat1 value2
3 data cat1 value3
4 data cat1 value4
5 data cat1 value5
6 data cat2    aaa
7 data cat2    bbb
8 data cat2    ccc
9 info
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted your answer. Just a minor question, if cat1 or cat2 has more than 10 values, the code "rowname = substr(rowname, 1, nchar(rowname) - 1)" will cause problem. Do you know how to fix this?